# Provision Android Lollipop devices without default encryption

Tags: android, encryption, provisioning, device-owner

I am unable to circumvent the default encryption on Lollipop devices while doing a device owner provisioning with NFC.

What I want to achieve is to provision an android device into device owner mode, with the following requirements:

- on Android versions 5.0 and 5.1
- provisioning happens via NFC during initial device setup
- **without encrypting the device**

Is this possible?

I know I can skip encryption on SDK 23 and onwards with an intent extra, but this is not the case on Lollipop. Also, the whole process could be skipped with the dpm tool through adb shell, though this is not an option.